# Python Equivalent of MATLAB's deval

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

As the title suggests, I am looking for an equivalent function or a suggestion on how to achieve the same thing deval does in MATLAB but in Python.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#define model function that returns ds/dt, di/dt/ and dr/dt

def epidemic_model(state, t):
     s, i, r = state
     d_s = -0.06 * s * i
     d_i = 0.06 *s * i - 7*i
     d_r = 7 * i
     return [d_s, d_i, d_r]


t = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
init_state = [990, 10, 0]

state = odeint(epidemic_model, init_state, t)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('population') 
plt.plot(t, state)
```

**Now my task is to find at which time the number of the infected population and recovered population is the same.**

I would do this in MATLAB using deval, I am looking for a Python version of this.

Answer (score 1):

Check `dsolve` function in the `sympy` package below:

http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/ode.html#dsolve

> Solves any (supported) kind of ordinary differential equation and system of ordinary differential equations.

Also, solve a system of ordinary differential equations using `integrate.solve_ivp` from `scipy` package:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy-integrate-solve-ivp

> This function numerically integrates a system of ordinary differential equations given an initial value

Comment: Thanks, to elaborate on my problem:  I am redoing a numerical analysis homework that I did in MATLAB in Python. I have 3 ODE's for a epidemic model which I solved with odeint. I will post the code in the original post.

Comment: @TommyOfinger: You can also use: `odeint` in `scipy` here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html

Comment: I have updated the answer with `integrate.solve_ivp` from `scipy`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp

Comment: Thank you for you help, please see my edited original post.